# C++ put byte array to function

Tags: c++, byte

Why if I send a command to `DeviceIoControl`:

```
byte lpInBuffer[44] = { 0x2C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01... };
byte lpOutBuffer[88];

BOOL result = DeviceIoControl(open, 0x0004D004, lpInBuffer, sizeof(lpInBuffer), &lpOutBuffer, sizeof(lpOutBuffer), 0x00000000, 0x00000000);

err = GetLastError(); //
cout << "result:" << result << ", err: " << err << "\n";
```

result is ok!

But if I do this, I get an error in result:

```
void putMessage(HANDLE handle, int type, int output_len, byte message[]) {
    byte* lpOutBuffer = new byte[output_len];
    byte* lpInBuffer = message;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(lpInBuffer); i++) {
        cout << lpInBuffer[i];
    }

    BOOL result = DeviceIoControl(handle, type, lpInBuffer, sizeof(lpInBuffer), &lpOutBuffer, sizeof(lpOutBuffer), 0x00000000, 0x00000000);


    int err = GetLastError();
    cout << "result:" << result << ", err: " << err << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(lpOutBuffer); i++) {
        cout << lpOutBuffer[i];
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
}

putMessage(open, 0x0004D004, 88, new byte[44]{ 0x2C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01... });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working:

```
void putMessage(HANDLE handle, int type, int output_size, vector<byte> input) {
    vector<byte> output(output_size);

    cout << "lpInBuffer:" << input.size() << ", lpOutBuffer: " << output.size() << "\n";

    BOOL result = DeviceIoControl(handle, type, input.data(), input.size(), (void*)output.data(), output.size(), 0x00000000, 0x00000000);

    int err = GetLastError(); // 5 i.e. ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
    cout << "result:" << result << ", err: " << err << "\n";


    for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
        cout << hexToString(output[i]) << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example you're dealing with variables of *array* type, and the `sizeof` of such a type is the (compile time constant known) size of the array in units of elements with `CHAR_BITS` bits.

In the second code example you're not working on variables of array type but on variables of *pointer* type. The size of a pointer is independent of the (possibly at compile time unknown) size of the array it may point to.

To solve this you need to pass also the `message` size to your function. From within your function use that size as well as the output buffer size instead of those `sizeof` expressions.

Comment: Hi! I added for clarity code:  `cout << "\n" << sizeof(message) << "\n" << 
  sizeof(lpInBuffer) << "\n" << 
  output_len << "\n" << 
  sizeof(lpOutBuffer) << "\n";` and i got that size byte array is 8: `8
8
96
8`, but byte array `message` len is 44